# Mapping Struts 1.1 tags to HTML & JSTL

Tags: spring-mvc, tags, migration, struts-1

I am working on migrating a software module from Struts 1.1 to the Spring MVC Framework. After doing some research, one of the first steps is to convert Struts tags to their HTML/JSTL equivalents.

However, I don't have experience with Struts (I just graduated), and my PM's opinion is that I don't need to learn Struts since they are migrating everything away from Struts. The online resources I found is useful in walking me through the migration process, but it doesn't give me a complete table of tag mappings, only a few examples (5-6).

I don't know how to identify Struts tags, much less know what is its Spring-compatible equivalent. I suspect the .jsp files are already in HTML, but I can't say for sure since I won't know a Struts tag when I see one. Is there any resource or reference I can refer to in order to help me in this respect? A list of Struts tags and/or a list for HTML/JSTL. It's best if there's a list of such mappings.

Note that installation/downloading of additional software/libraries etc. is out of the question. The project is on a separate network not connected to the Internet, so I can only use native libraries.

Comment: The JSP files are already in JSP. They *render* HTML, and consist mostly of HTML, but they're JSP. You *will* know a Struts tag when you see one, because taglibs are identified by taglib directives. The Struts 1 docs have complete tag documentation.

Comment: I've done a bit more research. Am I correct to say that 1) The struts tags use in a `.jsp` file are defined in the included `.tld` file, so if there's no taglib directive present to include any `.tld` file in the `.jsp` file, then that means there's no struts tags used in that file? 2) All struts tags in the `.jsp` file are prefixed with `struts:`?

Comment: They're prefixed with whatever the taglib directive defines. Each JSP that uses custom tags will have a taglib directive, but a taglib directive doesn't mean there are tags in the file.